# Mafia 3 - the procedure entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library vcruntime140.dll

Tags: visual-c++, dll

I'm on **Windows 8.1 64 bit**. I'm having a problem while running **Mafia 3** game. The error initially was about some dll missing. I got them from dll-files.com. Like I got 13 missing dlls (file name like **api-win-ms-crt-*-l1-1-0.dll**) from there and copied them to game directory. Now the final error pops up while opening the game is **the procedure entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library vcruntime140.dll** I wasted a whole day and found that the files **msvcp140.dll** and **vcruntime140.dll** are coming from installing **ms visual c++ 2015 redistributable**. I tried windows update, re-installing vc++ 2015, and the OS itself several times and the problem still exists. Please help me. I donno where I'm going wrong. I'm really into playing the game.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: If this question is asked in the wrong site, forgive me. Suggest me where I can ask these kinda questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **resolved** the issue LOL. The problem was with the **Visual C++ 2015** as I said. But inorder to install **Visual C++ 2015**, I had to update Windows completely. I did 2 GB of Windows Update. Then uninstalled VC++ 2015 and reinstalled. Files with name **api-win-ms-crt-*-l1-1-0.dll** were part of the windows update. Now game’s working. But framerate is low. My GPU is a not fast enough.